# How to publish real time sensor data currently being stored in SQL database on ckan

Tags: ckan

I am trying to publishing real time data on the ckan platform. Our organisation collects sensor data (weather, air, humidity etc) which we want to expose. Our aim is to publish the real time data on ckan to make it accessible to the public so that they can develop applications using that data.

I am able to upload datasets using link, dataproxy and static datasets.
I could not find any feature that can help me feed the ckan resource with real time data every few minutes. Data.gov.uk has published few datasets which gets updated every few minutes. I want to implement the same functionality but couldn't find a useful feature and a procedure to go further with implementation

What will allow me to create real time data flows within ckan?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Datastore to regularly add data to a CKAN resource. Either use the HTTP API (http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html#the-datastore-api) to add to add rows, or use the PostgreSQL DB Table directly and the new rows will appear in the CKAN resource.

I did some preliminary work some time ago on visualizing live data coming in (https://ckan.org/2015/08/21/matthew-fullerton-and-some-interesting-ckan-extension-development/). It's open source but still needs some disentabgling and documentation.

Comment: I think so. The graph plotting is probably hidden in here (Github makes it so difficult to search forks):
https://github.com/smartlane/ckan
And the Geospatial stuff referenced in the blog post here:
https://github.com/smartlane/ckanext-geoview

Both projects have moved on significantly since then.